# I can not use the data I received while using AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

Is there any way to synchronize the data I get with asyncStorage?

I get data in BaseAction.js

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

async function getData() {
  let auth_token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  console.log(auth_token);
  return auth_token;
}
export{getData}
```

I want use this data in here

```
import {
    request,
    getData,
    api_url
  } from "./BaseAction";


  export function listTask(onComplete) {

    var auth_token = getData();
    console.log(auth_token); ////return[ _40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null]

    return request
      .get(api_url)
      .set("Authorization", "Token " + auth_token)
      .end(...
      );
  }
```

Comment: No. `async`/`await` does not make code synchronous. Why not just make `listTask` an `async function` so that it returns a promise for the request result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var auth_token = getData();
```

You should do this in an `async` function and put `await` in front of the `getData` (Which should probably be named something better, more informative)